# No template definition found for the current content magnolia 5.7.9

Tags: magnolia

I created a new component in Magnolia 5.7.9 in that I created a placeholder.ftl and placeholder.yaml in /templates/components and I can see them correctly under module resource files.

placeholder.yaml:

```
title: Placeholder
renderType: freemarker
templateScript: /xxx-module-versioning/templates/components/placeholder.ftl
```

placeholder.ftl

```
<p>Hello World! I'm a Placeholder Component.</p>
```

Here is the component in JCR that I programmatically create:
[image]

When this specific component renders it gives a rendering error: `info.magnolia.rendering.engine.RenderException: No template definition found for the current content`

> Caused by:
> info.magnolia.config.registry.Registry$NoSuchDefinitionException:
> /xxx-module-versioning/templates/components/placeholder.ftl
> at info.magnolia.config.registry.AbstractRegistry.getProvider(AbstractRegistry.java:136)
> ~[magnolia-configuration-5.7.9.jar:?]

Is there something I am missing or doing wrong with this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value of `mgnl:template` should not be script but the template definition, so something like `xxx-module-versioning:components/placeholder`.  More details can be found in [templating documentation](https://docs.magnolia-cms.com/product-docs/Templating/Template-definition.html).